# xslt eclipse tools hang when source xml is long

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am fairly new to xslt. I am using Eclipse to run and debug my XSLT. In order to do so I installed the following eclipse plugins:

[image]

Everything seems to work correctly and I can test my transformations but sometimes the transformation seems to stall and never finishes. I have been able to get past that by making my test source files smaller by removing some of the elements. That way the transformation seems to work fine.

Of course I have tried removing different elements in order to see which one was causing the transformation to stall but the only factor that seems to be really affecting this issue is the size of the source xml file.

Has anyone before faced this issue?

For your reference, here is my transformation, (*I was not able to add the sample source XML files due to body length limitations, but I have placed a zip files with two sample XML files to process. One of them is just a shorter version of the other one, the longuer one just stalls the shorter one works fine https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4952440/samplesourcexml.zip* )

#### XSLT File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes" />

<!-- Identity to copy all elements -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="copyElementAttributes">
    <!-- Copy all element attributes to the renamed element -->
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}"><xsl:value-of select="." />    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This takes care of tansformation 1.a -->
<xsl:template match="sec">
    <xsl:element name="sec{count(ancestor::sec)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<!-- This takes care of transformation 1.b and 1.c -->
<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:variable name="titlenumbering">
        <xsl:number level="multiple" count="sec" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="title{count(ancestor::sec)}">
        <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="*" /> <xsl:element name="numeracio{count(ancestor::sec)}"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="$titlenumbering" /> </xsl:element> -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Match p elements where the first preceding sibling is a title element. -->
<!-- this takes care of transformation 4. <p_title> -->
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="prelativepos">
        <xsl:number level="single" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="pabsolutepos">
        <xsl:number level="any" count="/article/body//p" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- This takes care of transformation 3. <p_first> -->
        <xsl:when test="$pabsolutepos = 1">
            <xsl:element name="p_first">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$prelativepos = 1">
            <p_title>
                <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </p_title>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

<!-- This takes care of transformation 5. <p_list> -->
<xsl:template match="list/p">
    <p_list>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </p_list>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Change <p> inside <abstract> to <p_abstract> -->
<xsl:template match="//abstract/p">
    <p_abstract>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </p_abstract>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This takes care of transformation 6. <p_bullet> -->
<xsl:template match="list[@list-type='bullet']/p">
    <p_bullet>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </p_bullet>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This takes care of transformation 7. <p_simple> -->
<xsl:template match="list[@list-type='simple']/p">
    <p_simple>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </p_simple>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This takes care of transformation 8. <p_ordered> -->
<xsl:template match="list[@list-type='ordered']/p">
    <p_ordered>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </p_ordered>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Transformation 9. still has to be taken care of -->
<!-- Must clarify with customer how is avanttitle present in the xml -->

<!-- Transformation 10. still has to be taken care of -->
<!-- Must clarify with customer how is subtitle present in the xml -->

<!-- This takes care of transfomration 11. Entradeta <p content_type="entradeta"> -->
<xsl:template match="p[@content-type='entradeta']">
    <entradeta>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </entradeta>
</xsl:template>


<!-- This takes care of 12. <title> rigth after title to <title#nospace> -->
<xsl:template match="//title[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]]">
    <xsl:element name="title{count(ancestor::sec)}nospace">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This deals with bibliographical references <label> filled with sequence 
    number. rule 13 -->
<xsl:template match="//back/ref-list/ref/label">
    <xsl:variable name="labelval" select="." />
    <label>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::ref)+1" />
        <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> -->
    </label>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Replace xref by the number in lable and define as bibliographic xreference. 
    Rule 13 -->
<xsl:template match="//xref[@ref-type='bibr']">
    <xsl:variable name="rid" select="@rid" />
    <biblio_xref>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:attribute name="rid">
            <xsl:value-of select="$rid" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of
            select="count(//ref-list/ref[@id=$rid]/preceding-sibling::ref)+1" />
    </biblio_xref>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Deal with tags inside the statemenet tag. Rule 14 -->
<xsl:template match="//statement/p">
    <p_statement>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </p_statement>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//statement/title">
    <statement_author>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </statement_author>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <label> inside of <fig> must be tranformed to <pfignum> and must contain 
    figure sequence number. rule 15 and rule 2.a -->
<xsl:template match="//fig/label">
    <pfignum>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::fig)+1" />
    </pfignum>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <title> inside <caption> transformed to <pfigtext>. Rule 16 -->
<xsl:template match="//caption/title">
    <pfigtext>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </pfigtext>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Replace xref of type figure by the number in lable and define as figure 
    xreference. rule 23 -->
<xsl:template match="//xref[@ref-type='fig']">
    <xsl:variable name="rid" select="@rid" />
    <fig_xref>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />

        <xsl:value-of select="count(//fig[@id=$rid]/preceding-sibling::fig)+1" />
    </fig_xref>
</xsl:template>



<!-- Tables transformes into indesign namespace. rule 17 -->
<xsl:template match="//table">
    <xsl:attribute name="xmlns:aid">http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="xmlns:aid5">http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <label> inside <table-wrap> transfomed to <tablenum> and secuence order 
    added in tablenum element. rule 18 -->
<xsl:template match="//table-wrap/label">
    <tablenum>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::table-wrap)+1" />
    </tablenum>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <caption> inside <table-wrap> transformed to <tablecaption>. rule 19 -->
<xsl:template match="//table-wrap">
    <tablecaption>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </tablecaption>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Pending to implement rules 20 (Table related transformations) -->

<!-- Boxed text inside the <boxed_text> :Rule 21 <title> transformed to 
    <boxed_text_title> <label> transformed to <boxed_text_label> <p> transformed 
    to <boxed_text_p> -->

<xsl:template match="//boxed_text/title">
    <boxed_text_title>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </boxed_text_title>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//boxed_text/label">
    <boxed_text_label>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </boxed_text_label>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//boxed_text/p">
    <boxed_text_p>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </boxed_text_p>
</xsl:template>

<!-- For foot notes, <p> inside <fn> inside <fn-group> transformed into 
    <boxed_text_footnote>. Rule 22 -->
<xsl:template match="//fn-group/fn/p">
    <boxed_text_footnote>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </boxed_text_footnote>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Xref to tables transformed to <tab_xref> and corresponding table number 
    . rule 24 -->
<xsl:template match="//xref[@ref-type='tab']">
    <xsl:variable name="rid" select="@rid" />
    <tab_xref>
        <xsl:call-template name="copyElementAttributes" />
        <xsl:value-of
            select="count(//table-wrap[@id=$rid]/preceding-sibling::table-wrap)+1" />
    </tab_xref>
</xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Maybe your XSLT is very inefficient, which is why reducing the size of the XML "fixes" the issue. Can you update your question with some of the XSLT that you are using?

Comment: Thank you Mathew. I have extended my question to add the source code of the XSLT. Could not add sample XML files to process but have placed a link to download a zip file.

Comment: I used to use [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) when I developed XSLT. It includes a profile feature. Maybe that could help you.

Comment: Like @LaurentLegrand I use [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) as well. Works with both Mac and Windows platform. Instead of eclipse, I also use [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) which also works for both Mac and Windows environment. I run 10s of thousands of lines of code without a problem with these tools.

Comment: I have been browsing the links you provide to xsltproc but I can't find were to download it from.

Comment: Seems I found something ... but I need to download the libxslt package. I was looking for something with the xsltproc name. I also found this url that seems to have step by step instructions: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/InstallingAProcessor.html

Comment: I have tried xsltproc and it can process my transformation without any issues. Unfortunately the xalan 2.1.1 default processor provided by eclipse still freezes when using it.